# Multibyte Character not displayed correctly when loaded from Excel File using Apache POI in Java

Tags: java, character-encoding, apache-poi

I have an Excel file, which contains a symbol ().

When I read this file in, all I get printed to the console is a square symbol with question mark inside it.

When I copy from either the console output, or the original file - some applications paste it correctly (the symbol), others instead just show "ᨅ".

This symbol is a multibyte character.

When I try to write this symbol out to a file, no matter which encoding I use, it is never displayed correctly in Notepad or Notepad++.

In my application I am seeing the symbol displayed as "ᨅ", but when working backwards I cannot seem to do anything with this symbol.

The Excel file can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8co7fgj848pqven/input.xlsx?dl=0).

The code I am using to read this file (using Apache POI) is below.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception
{
    final String desktop = System.getenv("USERPROFILE") + File.separator + "Desktop" + File.separator; //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$

    // Read in input file from Desktop
    try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(desktop + "input.xlsx"), null, true)) //$NON-NLS-1$
    {
        // Get the first cell
        final String str = workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();

        // Print some analysis on the String
        final String format = "%-30s%-25s%n"; //$NON-NLS-1$
        System.out.format(format, "Representation of String", str); //$NON-NLS-1$
        System.out.format(format, "Length of String", str.length()); //$NON-NLS-1$
        System.out.format(format, "Code Point Length of String", str.codePointCount(0, str.length())); //$NON-NLS-1$
        System.out.format(format, "Multi-byte Characters", Character.isSurrogatePair(str.charAt(0), str.charAt(1))); //$NON-NLS-1$

        // Write out the String using all available encodings listed in java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.
        for (final Field field : StandardCharsets.class.getDeclaredFields())
        {
            if (field.getType().equals(Charset.class))
            {
                final Charset charset = (Charset) field.get(null);

                Files.write(Paths.get(desktop + "out_" + charset.name() + ".txt"), str.getBytes(charset), StandardOpenOption.CREATE); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your linked file is `input.xlsx` but your code loads `input.xls`. This is a difference.

Comment: Also what `apache poi` version are you using? And what is `System.out` in your case?  Your code works as expected using `apache poi` version `3.17` in Ubuntu Linux where `System.out` is bash which is able showing Unicode properly. And using `apache poi` version `3.17` in Windows 10 the files `out_UTF-8.txt` and `out_UTF-16.txt`  are correct even if the `CMD` cannot show Unicode properly.,

Comment: @AxelRichter I actually tried both .xls & .xlsx (saving from Excel each time). Neither worked. I accidentally uploaded the code with the .xls. I've edited this.

Comment: @AxelRichter I'm using POI 3.17. Both my example code and my actual application are running on Windows 7, using Eclipse set to UTF-8 mode. And none of the text files - even the ones you've mentioned - render correctly in either Notepad or Notepad++.

If I open the Excel file as an archive and look at the underlying XML that contains the symbol, even here in Notepad++ it does not render correctly.

Comment: :"If I open the Excel file as an archive and look at the underlying XML that contains the symbol, even here in Notepad++ it does not render correctly." Then this is a Notepad++ problem. The Office Open XML files within a `*.xlsx` ZIP archive saved from Excel are always `UTF-8` encoded. Of course there is not a `BOM`, also not in the files saved from your code. So maybe Notepad++ has a problem detecting the UTF encoding without a `BOM`?  But as said my Windows 10 Notepad opens at least the two mentioned files properly.

Comment: To make it clear. When I am opening the `/xl/sharedStrings.xml` form your `input.slsx` archive using Notepad from Windows 10, I see: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><sst xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" count="1" uniqueCount="1"><si><t></t></si></sst>`.

Comment: @AxelRichter I've tested on Windows 10 from Eclipse and it renders fine from the console. So now it appears to be a Windows 7 vs Windows 10 encoding issue?

Comment: It appears to be a good example for how less Unicode support had been in former Windows. Good to see that this seems has been changed now finally.

Comment: @AxelRichter I've also noticed that in Windows 7 on Eclipse, it doesn't work - but Windows 7 on IntelliJ it does. On Windows 10 on Eclipse it does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments already, this is not a `apache poi` problem but a `Windows 7` and `Notepad++` problem.

After all I have started my `Windows 7` virtual machine once again (hopefully last time now ;-)). The `Windows 7` system does not even providing a font having glyphs for that kind of Unicode code point. So it is pretty clear that nothing what relies on the system can show this  emoji properly. Some Browsers (Firefox and Chrome for example) provide own fonts and so are able showing this. As @Jakg commented, seems `IntelliJ` also does that while `Eclipse` does not.

Other systems, `Ubuntu` linux and `Windows 10` are able showing the emoji properly. Of course `Windows 10` always nor not in the `CMD` command window. But inside of IDEs which have their own `System.out` print writer even the `System.out` shows it.

And while creating the text files one could make the detecting the encoding easier for text editors later by putting a `BOM` (Byte Order Mark) as the first bytes of the text file. Some `Charset`s (`UTF-16` for example) does this per default but others not. Then we must providing this in the program.

So after the following code even `Notepad++` should be able detecting the encoding correctly because all `*.txt` files will have a `BOM`.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;

import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

class ExcelReadUnicode {

 public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("input.xlsx"))) {

   String str = workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();

   String format = "%-30s%-25s%n";
   System.out.format(format, "Representation of String", str);
   System.out.format(format, "Length of String", str.length());
   System.out.format(format, "Code Point Length of String", str.codePointCount(0, str.length()));
   System.out.format(format, "Multi-byte Characters", Character.isSurrogatePair(str.charAt(0), str.charAt(1)));

   Charset[] charsets = new Charset[] {
                               StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE, 
                               StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE, 
                               StandardCharsets.UTF_8
                              }; // those charsets needs BOMs manually added

   for (Charset charset : charsets ) {
    Files.write(Paths.get("out_" + charset.name() + ".txt"), 
                ("\uFEFF" + str).getBytes(charset), // write out a BOM before the content
                StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING); 
   }

   Files.write(Paths.get("out_" + StandardCharsets.UTF_16.name() + ".txt"), 
               str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16), // UTF-16 puts BOM per default
               StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING); 
  }

 }

}
```

Btw.: The term "Charset" is misused for Unicode encodings. The Unicode character set is Unicode always and is always the same. The different `UTF` (Unicode Transformation Format) are different encoding formats for that one Unicode character set.

Comment: Thanks again. It's great you've got the file encoding working, but this doesn't fix my actual problem (my fault - I didn't discuss the problem in my question!). If it just doesn't work on Windows 7 that's much easier to understand. Let me test my application on Windows 10. And apologies to any POI developer I may of inadvertently offended by suggesting a bug!

Comment: @Jakg: Hm, no it is not the case that Unicode code points as this emoji "just doesn't work on Windows 7". It only is not displayable in the system and all applications which relying on the system. This is because of lack a system font having glyphs for this. Only applications providing own fonts are able showing this. So don't think : "It does not work." only because you cannot see the glyph correctly.